# Rotating Images all load for a second when the page is first accessed

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, rotator

I am trying to create a simple rotating bunch of slides (5 total) that contain links to their respective pages. I found a simple code that seems to work but when the page is loaded for the first time it loads all five images for a second before the slide show starts. Is there a way to hide the other images when the page first loads?

My test page is located here: http://www.northeastern.edu/test/coe/test.html

The page is part of a larger CMS and the part I am editing is in the panoramic div in the center of the page. When I try to load just this part outside the CMS it seems to work ok but I can't get it to work all together.

This is the code that I added:

```
    <div id="panoramic">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
      <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js" ></script>
      <script>
        $('.rotator').cycle({
          speed: 500,
          fx: 'fade',
          timeout: 6000
        });
      </script>

      <div class="rotator">
        <div><p><a href="link0"><img alt="" src="header00.png" /></a></p></div>
        <div><p><a href="link1"><img alt="" src="header01.png" /></a></p></div>
        <div><p><a href="link2"><img alt="" src="header02.png" /></a></p></div>
        <div><p><a href="link3"><img alt="" src="header03.png" /></a></p></div>
        <div><p><a href="link4"><img alt="" src="header04.png" /></a></p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all the ones that aren't going to be visible at the start using inline css.

```
  <div class="rotator">
    <div><p><a href="link0"><img alt="" src="header00.png" /></a></p></div>
    <div style="display: none;"><p><a href="link1"><img alt="" src="header01.png" /></a></p></div>
    <div style="display: none;"><p><a href="link2"><img alt="" src="header02.png" /></a></p></div>
    <div style="display: none;"><p><a href="link3"><img alt="" src="header03.png" /></a></p></div>
    <div style="display: none;"><p><a href="link4"><img alt="" src="header04.png" /></a></p></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is mostly css related... you haven't set any css at all for slide container, or slide elements. If you disable javascript on the page, you will see that your `rotator` container simply expands to the height of all it's content. This is all controllable with css.

Currently you are waiting for page ready event to set the css for you which is late in the page load process, whereas css gets processed immediately.

Give the slide container some dimensions. Then when you add `overflow:hidden` the images beyond the bounds of the element can't be seen.

Example css rule to place in stylesheet:

```
.rotator{
   width: 700px;
   height:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```